# Rails has_many assign child ids renders parent invalid because parent must have a child

Tags: ruby-on-rails, has-many

here are the model associations

```
class Driver
  has_many :cars

  validates :cars, presence: true
end
```

```
class Car
  belongs_to :driver
end
```

The car records already exists. It does not need to have a driver

first car with id 1, gets assigned to driver 1

```
driver1.car_ids = [1]
```

driver1 now has a car

Now we create driver 2 with car 1

```
driver2.car_ids = [1]
```

driver1 becomes invalid, because it no longer has cars

What is the best way to handle this?

Comment: What do you mean invalid? Can you provide a sequence of commands that lead to an unintended backtrace or output?

Comment: invalid as in fails validation for cars presence true. There is no backtrace, everything succeeds

Answer (score 1):

The reason this is failing is because, in your current setup, a car can only have one driver. Since you assign driver1 to the car and then assign driver2 to the car, driver2 overrides driver1, making driver2 the cars owner. If you want to have many drivers in a car, you should change your setup to this:

```
class Car
  has_many :drivers
end
```

This will allow you to assign many drivers (or only one driver, if that’s the intention) to your car.

Answer (score 0):

Your association fails as while a driver can have many cars in your setup, a car belongs to one driver. You need to use a join table and a has_and_belongs_to_many association.

[Ruby on Rails Guides - has_and_belongs_to_many](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-and-belongs-to-many-association)